# Azure DevOps Android build failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting below error while building my Android Flutter app through Azure DevOps build pipeline since Oct 13th, 2023.  Has anyone faced same error know of solution for this?

2023-10-15T19:48:59.9640711Z [        ] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.1591878Z [ +199 ms] > Task :add_2_calendar:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
2023-10-15T19:49:00.1593089Z [        ] AAPT2 aapt2-7.2.0-7984345-linux Daemon #0: shutdown
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2672467Z [ +100 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2673261Z [   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2674406Z [        ] Execution failed for task ':add_2_calendar:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2675106Z [        ] > error: invalid source release: 17
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2675753Z [        ] * Try:
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2676235Z [        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2677033Z [        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2677512Z [        ] * Exception is:
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2678673Z [        ] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':add_2_calendar:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2680135Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2681513Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2682633Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2684238Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2685596Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2687162Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2688614Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2690254Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2691575Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2693059Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2694404Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2695883Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2697141Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2698768Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2700372Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2702531Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2703623Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2704723Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2705814Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2706880Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2708327Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2709409Z [        ]     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2710605Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2711757Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2713112Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2714520Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2715978Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2717232Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2718229Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2719140Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:115)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2720155Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:135)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2721268Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:120)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2722457Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:35)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2723417Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2724564Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2725930Z [        ]     at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2727337Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2728769Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2730025Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2731138Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2732250Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2733341Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2734413Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
2023-10-15T19:49:00.2735475Z [        ]     at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)